# Intersection of lattice polytopes

Tags: co.combinatorics, lattice-polytopes

Is there a way to characterise when the intersection of two or more lattice polytopes is again a lattice polytope? For instance, can you read that property from their Ehrhart polynomials?  If it makes things any easier, those polytopes are hollow, namely, they don't have internal lattice points.

Comment: Is a lattice polytope defined as a convex hull of finitely many lattice points, not all in the same hyperplane?

Comment: I don’t think there can be any really simple criterion for this.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point, the polytopes can be assumed to be full dimensional, so their vertices don't lie in a common hyperplane.